# phpMyAdmin Version 4.3.x very slow behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, performance, phpmyadmin

I used phpMyAdmin for many years and it is a great open source solution to manage my mysql databases. But since version 4.3 the behaviour of the software is very very slow. When I oppend a table to view the entries, it takes 5 - 10 seconds to show the result. Also when I make a simple search question or do anything else.

Has anyone else also such problems?

Comment: "view the entries" -- How big is the table?  Do all actions take 5-10 seconds?  Which do, which don't?

Comment: The size of the tables doesn't matter. When I try to view a table it takes 5-10 seconds until phpMyAdmin answers. Also when I make a search, the response takes 5-10 seconds. And something else: when I tried to add new columns, I only get a white page :-(